# "This is the first year" + clause

Tags: grammar, tenses, syntactic-analysis

In a sentence such as

> This is the first year I’ve lived in a house with a yard.

Is it all right to have a clause other than present perfect? That is, can you say, for instance, sentences like the following:

> This is the first year I'm living in a house with a yard
>
> That was the first year I lived in a house with a yard.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you may have a clause in such a time-based sentence using cases other than present perfect. The following are all fine:

> This is the first year I'm living in a house with a yard.
>   That was the first year I lived in a house with a yard.
>   That was the first year I'd lived in a house with a yard.
>   This will be the first year I'll be living in a house with a yard.
>   This will be the first year I'm living in a house with a hard.

And so on.

Comment: What about "...I'm going to live..."? What tense can it take in the first clause? I was thinking of "This is/This will be".

Comment: @Alenanno: Your instincts are correct. Either of those would work.